# `sg` command does not forward sigterm

Tags: signals

When I run

```
bash -c 'trap "echo TERM" SIGTERM; id;read'
```

And send a SIGTERM to it, it simply echos `TERM`, however when I do

```
sg docker "bash -c 'trap \"echo TERM\" SIGTERM; id;read'"
```

The process actually terminates. Is it wrong to expect sg to forward the signals to the called command.

Comment: I guess it's a matter of opinion. `timeout` relays signals, but `su`, `sg`, `time`, `dash`, and even `bash` don't (except for signals like HUP). [Try `bash -c "true;bash -c 'trap \"echo TERM\" SIGTERM; id;read'"` ]

Comment: Well at least in the case of bash you can tell it to `exec` the child process

Comment: Is your question more like "how can I kill an entire tree of processes that a single command has spawned?" Because you can do that by sending a signal to a process group, if the shell supports job control.  I think I can find an existing question/answer about that.

Comment: the original problem is that I want to start a docker container process with a certain group id (at least that's what https://github.com/dperson/openvpn-client/blob/master/openvpn.sh#L252 does) However, `docker stop` sends a term, but that never trickles down to the openvpn process.